# What are Industrial Case Studies and why are they required?

Tags: industry, independent-researcher

I searched on the internet about this but found no convincing answer. I have to submit a paper to a conference where they are also asking for an Industrial Case Study. I contacted the conference chair about this, they replied:

> If there is a pragmatic solution to a problem or there is an innovative application developed then an Industrial Case Study is required. For more details you may search for case study submissions for similar conferences.

The domain is KDD (Knowledge Discovery in Databases). I did search but did not find any good stuff.

Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Did you want help in understanding why Industrial Case Studies are required or do you want help with finding some?  or both?

Comment: I basically want to know what are they ? Why are they needed ... are the different from a research paper ?

Comment: Thank you for that clarification - in that case, definitely upvoted as it would be interesting to learn about these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An industrial case study is when you take your solutions or your processes, apply it to some situation in industry, and then report on the results. You might use the [Case Study Method research method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1452242569) if what you propose can be appropriately investigated using a qualitative case study. This is appropriate if you're in management sciences, human-computer interaction, and software engineering (which is what the Damian paper referenced above is about). Note that industrial case studies of this type are VERY difficult to do and take an extremely long time to write up and report on, so I actually doubt the conference is looking for this kind of case study.

Alternatively, in the field of Knowledge Discovery of Databases, an industrial case study may simply be applying your algorithm to a database that is used in industry to discover something novel or meaningful. This is more common for analytical fields in general and simply requires you to acquire a database or some other data source that was generated through industrial activity.

The reason for "industrial case studies" is because a lot of people create methods and techniques and test it only with "fake laboratory data" that they happen to create or acquire. This fake laboratory data doesn't reflect very accurately the real world and people want to see that techniques in fact work on, affect and influence the real world.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a specific definition; however, I found a few Industrial Case Study examples from your and similar fields that may be useful analogs for you to model your case study off:

["An Industrial Case Study of Immediate Benefits of
Requirements Engineering Process Improvement at
the Australian Center for Unisys Software"](http://alarcos.esi.uclm.es/doc/metotecinfinf/articulos/4-damian-casestudy-ese-2004.pdf) (Damian et al. 2004).

["http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA446147"](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA446147) (Cook and Wolf)

["Process Monitoring using a Combination of Data driven Techniques
and Model based Data Validation"](http://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/4182/1/Extended_T3-245.pdf) (Duchesne et al. 2007)

["Signed Directed Graph Based Modeling and its Validation from Process Knowledge and Process Data"](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/amc/amc22/amc2213.pdf) (Yang et al. 2012)

Answer (score 0):

I contacted one the authors on the papers UV-D mentioned and according to the author:

> "Industrial Case Study"  means the results presented have been validated in actual plant operation, they are not only based on theoretical considerations.

I even asked this question on Google+'s Machine Learning Community. You can have a look at the converstaion [here](https://plus.google.com/117281960538042233493/posts/JxxxvbNsXom).